# Transparent Huge Pages, Pagetable size and /proc/<pid>/status

Tags: virtual-memory

TL;DR; My pagetable is far bigger than it should be when using transparent huge pages (THP).

I have a program (see below), that allocates 50 GiB of memory, requests transparent huge pages and faults them.

Through `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/<pid>/smaps` I can verify that THP are actually allocated.

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep AnonHugePages
AnonHugePages:  52426752 kB
```

One advantage of huge pages is that the pagetable gets smaller roughly 512 fold. It's only three levels instead of four and instead of having 512 PTEs with each 8 bytes in size (on x64), there is only one PMD entry. So one supposedly saves 512 * 8 = 4 KiB in PTEs per 2MiB of memory. However, when I check the pagetable size in /proc//status, it tells me that I have 100MiB worth of page descriptors. That would make sense if I were using 4 KiB pages (50 GiB / 4 KiB * 8 = 100 MiB), but with 2 MiB pages I would expect there to not be many PTEs and so VmPTE should be some small number close to zero. Only things using PTEs should be code pages, stack, glibc, etc. Everything that's not mapped with thp.

```
buchgra@hyper2:~$ cat /proc/24116/status | egrep "VmPTE|VmPMD"
VmPTE:    102444 kB 
VmPMD:       212 kB
```

The THP also don't show up in /proc/24116/numa_maps and so on.

Does anyone know why? Are those stats maybe not aware of THP i.e. is transparent huge pages that transparent?

Thanks!

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   constexpr size_t SIZE_50GiB = 50ull << 30;
   void *p = mmap(NULL, SIZE_50GiB, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
   madvise(p, SIZE_50GiB, MADV_HUGEPAGE);
   memset(p, 1, SIZE_50GiB);

   printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());
   sleep(10000);

  return 0;
}
```